# turning the json result into dynamic

Tags: json, swift, xcode, object, cocoapods

i have a very complicated issue for a beginner. firstly I have this result from json

```
{
  "success": true,
  "timeframe": true,
  "start_date": "2018-01-01",
  "end_date": "2018-01-05",
  "source": "TRY",
  "quotes": {
    "2018-01-01": {
      "TRYEUR": 0.21947
    },
    "2018-01-02": {
      "TRYEUR": 0.220076
    },
    "2018-01-03": {
      "TRYEUR": 0.220132
    },
    "2018-01-04": {
      "TRYEUR": 0.220902
    },
    "2018-01-05": {
      "TRYEUR": 0.222535
    }
  }
}
```

and when I use https://app.quicktype.io to create the object for me it gives this and that is right.

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - APIResult
struct APIResult {
    let success, timeframe: Bool
    let startDate, endDate, source: String
    let quotes: [String: Quote]
}

// MARK: - Quote
struct Quote {
    let tryeur: Double
}
```

but I don't want my currencies hardcoded like this so if I choose from: USD to : EUR in my app I want to get the result under Quote as USDEUR. And I also know that if I change anything in this struct it won't work. So how will make those currency selections dynamic to make it work in different currencies. This is a currency converter app and I want to get these rates and reflect it on a chart in my app. Thank you.

Edit: I think I need to get used to using stack overflow properly. Sorry for any inconvenience . At last I could get the dates and rates written in the console. my question is now :

how can i get these results in the console passed into my charts x(dates) and y axis(rates) ?

```
["2022-12-22": 19.803011, "2022-12-18": 19.734066, "2022-12-23": 19.907873, "2022-12-21": 19.79505, "2022-12-24": 19.912121, "2022-12-17": 19.756527, "2022-12-16": 19.752446, "2022-12-25": 19.912121, "2022-12-19": 19.794356, "2022-12-20": 19.824031]
```

this is the func i get these

```
func updateChart () {
    
    let date = Date()
    let endDate = formatter.string(from: date)
    let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -9, to: date)
    let startDatee = formatter.string(from: startDate ?? Date())
    print(endDate)
    print(startDatee)
    let result: () = currencyManager.fetchRatesForTimeframe(from: from, to: to, startDate: startDatee, endDate: endDate)
    print(result)
   }
```

and this is my previously created and hardcoded charts

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        lineChart.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 240)
        lineChart.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(lineChart)
       
       var entries = [ChartDataEntry]()
        
        for x in 0..<10 {
            
            entries.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(x), y: Double(x)))
        }
        
        let set = LineChartDataSet(entries: entries)
        
        set.colors = ChartColorTemplates.material()
        
        let data = LineChartData(dataSet: set)
        lineChart.data = data
    }
```

Comment: Here you have two options, change the structure of your value object to be something like `{ units: "TRYEUR", value: 0.22535 }`

or delete the Quote struct and also just use a dictionary like `let quotes: [String: [String: number]]`

Comment: I see. First option is a little hard to understand for me for now . Is it a closure and why do we set hardcoded values inside that?

Answer (score 1):

`Decodable` is pretty versatile and highly customizable.

Write a custom initializer and map the quote dictionary to an array of `Quote` instances which contains the date and the quote. The key `TRYEUR` is irrelevant and will be ignored.

```
let jsonString = """
{
  "success": true,
  "timeframe": true,
  "start_date": "2018-01-01",
  "end_date": "2018-01-05",
  "source": "TRY",
  "quotes": {
    "2018-01-01": {
      "TRYEUR": 0.21947
    },
    "2018-01-02": {
      "TRYEUR": 0.220076
    },
    "2018-01-03": {
      "TRYEUR": 0.220132
    },
    "2018-01-04": {
      "TRYEUR": 0.220902
    },
    "2018-01-05": {
      "TRYEUR": 0.222535
    }
  }
}
"""

struct APIResult: Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case success, timeframe, startDate = "start_date", endDate = "end_date", source, quotes
    }
    let success, timeframe: Bool
    let startDate, endDate, source: String
    let quotes: [Quote]
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        success = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .success)
        timeframe = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .timeframe)
        startDate = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .startDate)
        endDate = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .endDate)
        source =  try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .source)
        let quoteData = try container.decode([String: [String:Double]].self, forKey: .quotes)
        quotes = quoteData.compactMap({ (key, value) in
            guard let quote = value.values.first else { return nil }
            return Quote(date: key, quote: quote)
        }).sorted{$0.date < $1.date}
    }
}

struct Quote {
    let date: String
    let quote: Double
}


do {
    let result = try  JSONDecoder().decode(APIResult.self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8))
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: where do I insert my url and apikey here?

Comment: Just use your code to load the data from the API. My suggestion is a stand-alone version.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my api provider now but this new one is not that much different than the previous one . this is the response I get inside browser

```
    {
  "success": true,
  "timeseries": true,
  "start_date": "2022-04-01",
  "end_date": "2022-04-05",
  "base": "USD",
  "rates": {
    "2022-04-01": {
      "TRY": 14.686504
    },
    "2022-04-02": {
      "TRY": 14.686504
    },
    "2022-04-03": {
      "TRY": 14.686145
    },
    "2022-04-04": {
      "TRY": 14.696501
    },
    "2022-04-05": {
      "TRY": 14.72297
    }
  }
}
```

this is my object

```
struct APIResult: Codable {
    let timeseries: Bool
    let success: Bool
    let startDate: String
    let endDate: String
    let base: String
    var rates: [String:[String:Double]]
}
```

and this is my code inside VC to get the current date and 10 days before and I can see it printed in the console.

```
  lazy var formatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeZone = .current
        formatter.locale = .current
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return formatter
        
    }()
```

func updateChart () {

```
let date = Date()
let endDate = formatter.string(from: date)
let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -10, to: date)
let startDatee = formatter.string(from: startDate ?? Date())
print(endDate)
print(startDatee)
currencyManager.fetchRatesForTimeframe(from: from, to: to, startDate: startDatee, endDate: endDate)
```

lastly these are the codes inside my other file called CurrencyManager

```
func fetchRatesForTimeframe(from: String, to: String, startDate: String, endDate:String) {
        let urlString = "\(timeFrameUrl)base=\(from)&symbols=\(to)&start_date=\(startDate)&end_date=\(endDate)&apikey=\(api.convertApi)"
        performRequestforTimeframe(with: urlString)
  }

func performRequestforTimeframe(with urlString: String) {

                if let url = URL(string: urlString) {

                    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

                  let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

                        if error != nil {
                            print(error!)
                        } else {
                            if let safeData = data {

                               if let timeFrameRates = parseJSONForTimeframe(currencyData: safeData) {
                                   print(timeFrameRates)
                                   self.delegate?.didGetTimeframeRates(timeFrameRates)
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    task.resume()
                }
            }

    func cut(_ value: [String: [String: Double]]) -> [String: [String: Double]] {
        let dic = value
            .sorted(by: { $0.0 < $1.0 })[0..<10] // <-- last 10 results
            .reduce(into: [String: [String: Double]]()) {
                $0[$1.key] = $1.value
            }
        return dic
    }
    
    func parseJSONForTimeframe(currencyData: Data) -> APIResult? {

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            var jsondata = try decoder.decode(APIResult.self, from: currencyData)
            jsondata.rates = cut(jsondata.rates)
    
            return jsondata

            } catch {
           
            return nil
        }

    }

}
```

why I can't get the result for print(timeFrameRates) inside func performRequestforTimeframe ? what s missing?